# Regex; eliminate all punctuation except

Tags: r, regex, strsplit

I have the following regex that splits on any space or punctuation.  How can I exclude 1 or more punctuation characters from `:punct:`?  Let's say I'd like to exclude apostrophes and commas.  I know I could explicitly use `[all punctuation marks in here]` instead of `[[:punct:]]` but I'm hoping for an exclusion method.

```
X <- "I'm not that good at regex yet, but am getting better!"
strsplit(X, "[[:space:]]|(?=[[:punct:]])", perl=TRUE)

 [1] "I"       "'"       "m"       "not"     "that"    "good"    "at"      "regex"   "yet"    
[10] ","       ""        "but"     "am"      "getting" "better"  "!"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you want the result to be, but you might be able to use negative classes [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4786560/271616).

```
R> strsplit(X, "[[:space:]]|(?=[^,'[:^punct:]])", perl=TRUE)[[1]]
 [1] "I'm"     "not"     "that"    "good"    "at"      "regex"   "yet,"   
 [8] "but"     "am"      "getting" "better"  "!"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may impose a restriction to a PCRE subpattern directly with a `(?![',])` [**negative lookahead**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) that fails the match if the next char to the right is `'` or `,`:

```
[[:space:]]|(?=(?![',])[[:punct:]])
               ^^^^^^^^
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/s2lKog/1).

**Details**

- `[[:space:]]` - any whitespace
- `|` - or
- `(?=(?![',])[[:punct:]])` - a positive lookahead that requires that, immediately to the right of the current position, there is no `'` and `,` and that there is any 1 punctuation char that is not a `'` or `,` (effectively, requiring any punctuation symbol other than `'` and `,`).

See the [R online demo](https://ideone.com/gVEp0q)

```
X <- "I'm not that good at regex yet, but am getting better!"
strsplit(X, "[[:space:]]|(?=(?![',])[[:punct:]])", perl=TRUE)
[[1]]
 [1] "I'm"     "not"     "that"    "good"    "at"      "regex"   "yet,"   
 [8] "but"     "am"      "getting" "better"  "!"
```