# Selective regex on a word/character

Tags: regex, r

I'd like to replace all the cases of the word `Date` in a string unless it is `Date()` (that is Date followed by parenthesis).  Here's an example of a string and what I tried at first:

```
x <- c("frDate", "Date()", "Date", "Sys.Date()")
gsub("Date", paste("Date:", Sys.Date()), x)
```

**What I get:**

```
> gsub("Date", paste("Date:", Sys.Date()), x)
[1] "frDate: 2013-04-04"     "Date: 2013-04-04()"     "Date: 2013-04-04"      
[4] "Sys.Date: 2013-04-04()"
```

**What I'd like:**

```
> gsub("Date", paste("Date:", Sys.Date()), x)
[1] "frDate: 2013-04-04"     "Date()"     "Date: 2013-04-04"      
[4] "Sys.Date()"
```

I thought maybe I could learn from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372438/regex-eliminate-all-punctuation-except) on the matter:

```
gsub("(?=[^Date\\(\\)[^Date]])", paste("Date:", Sys.Date()), x)
```

Not so good.

*If someone has a better title to make this solution more general please change it so R regex users have a searchable means of handling exceptions.*

Comment: Is it possible the input will have the form "blah blah Date blah"?

Comment: In my case no but I was hoping to make a thread that was more generalizable to others Dason so let's pretend yes.

Comment: @Stedy I agree with the first part of your title change (and kept it) but the later part (with same name as built in) was just coincidental, it could have been `chicken` followed by `@`.  I coudn't find a thread here for R users that specifically addressed this problem (though I'm sure there is) and so I want to have one that has a title that's easy to search for.

Comment: good point, this is much better than mine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add to your pattern a negative lookahead assertion that matches an opening parenthesis. (You'll also have to set `perl=TRUE` to get this functionality.)

```
gsub("Date(?!\\()", paste("Date:", Sys.Date()), x, perl=TRUE)
[1] "frDate: 2013-04-04" "Date()"             "Date: 2013-04-04"  
[4] "Sys.Date()"
```

The name sounds intimidating, and I suspect the `#@!$%^&*`-like strings of symbols scare folks away, but it's really not that complicated:  just type `(?!...)`, replacing `...` by whatever pattern you would like to cause the entire regex **not** to match. Here, we'd like any string that starts out with `Date` but then continues with `(` not to match, so (escaping `(` because it's a special character) we write `(?!\\))`.

Comment: Both responses are very helpful.  Thank you for taking the time to explain this out in detail.

Comment: De nada. The four look-around assertions are so incredibly useful that I think it's worth taking 15-30 to play around with all four of them. That should be enough to make them a permanent part of your repertoire!

Comment: is this a decent looking tutorial or did you have something else in mind: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Looking_Ahead_and_Behind.html?

Comment: @TylerRinker Yeah, that looks fine. I tend to really like [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), and so (apparently) do lots of other folks. [Here's the section](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) devoted to lookaround assertions.

Answer (score 3):

`gsub('Date$', paste('Date:', Sys.Date()), x)`  work for you?

```
# [1] "frDate: 2013-04-04" "Date()" "Date: 2013-04-04"   "Sys.Date()"
```

The `$` operator in regular expressions indicates end of line.  This way, only values in `x` that end with `Date` are matched.  If you had a situation where you could have `blah blah Date blah` that you also wanted to match the regex would get significantly more complex.

You could also match `Date` followed by anything other than a `(` like this:

```
gsub('Date(?!\\()', paste('Date:', Sys.Date()), x, perl=TRUE)
```

Where the `?` marks the following as optional and the `!` is a negation of sorts.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to explain this in detail.  Hopefully this will be a thread that others can find useful with similar needs. +1