# strsplit on all spaces and punctuation except apostrophes

Tags: regex, r

I have asked related questions [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372438/regex-eliminate-all-punctuation-except) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697079/remove-all-punctuation-except-apostrophes-in-r).  I tried to generalize these answers but have failed.

Basically I have a string I want to split into words, numbers and any sort of punctuation, yet, I want to retain the apostrophes.  Here is what I've tried and I'm so close (I think):

```
x <- "Raptors don't like robots! I'd pay $500.00 to rid them."

strsplit(x, "(\\s+)|(?=[[:punct:]])", perl = TRUE)

## [[1]]
##  [1] "Raptors" "don"     "'"       "t"       "like"    "robots"  "!"             
##  [8] ""   "I"   "'"    "d"  "pay"     "$"       "500"     "."       "00"      "to"         
## [20] "rid"   "them"    "."
```

Here's what I'm after:

```
## [[1]]
##  [1] "Raptors" "don't"       "like"    "robots"  "!"       ""        "I'd"      
##  [8] "pay"     "$"       "500"   "."   "00"  "to"      "rid"     "them"    "."
```

While I want a base solution I would like to see other solutions (I'm sure someone has a stringr solution) which makes the question more generalizable to others.

***Note:*** *R has a specific regex system.  You will want to be familiar with R to answer this question.*

Comment: (Curious) What's specific about R's regex flavour?

Comment: I'm confused how the first question you link to is not exactly the same as this one?

Comment: @Jongware, there are issues with escaping special characters for example.

Comment: @eddi The first question removed the characters, here I'm not removing them, I want them.  I used info from those 2 questions to get me as far as I can (similar but not identical).

Comment: @TylerRinker can you illustrate with an example? For your current example: `identical(strsplit(x, "[[:space:]]|(?=[^'[:^punct:]])", perl=TRUE), strsplit(x, "(\\s+)|(?!')(?=[[:punct:]])", perl = TRUE))
# [1] TRUE
`

Comment: @eddi You are correct.  I was testing with a comma,hence why I thought they were different situations, but this is untrue as the other solution was explicitly not splitting on commas.  I voted to close.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a negative lookahead `(?!')`:

```
strsplit(x, "(\\s+)|(?!')(?=[[:punct:]])", perl = TRUE)
#  [1] "Raptors" "don't"   "like"    "robots"  "!"       ""        "I'd"     "pay"     "$"       "500"     "."       "00"      "to"      "rid"     "them"    "."
```