# R: Search words in one string in another string and return words which could not match

Tags: r, regex, string, datatable

My datatable has two text columns(`col1` and `col2`). Both have sentences in them. I want to look for all words in `col1` in `col2` and return a string that has words in `col1` minus the words that were found in `col2`. Below is an example

```
            col1                 |         col2             |     output
america, uk have too much money  |   uk, uk money too too   |  america, have much
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
DT <- data.table(col1 <- "america, uk have too much money", col2 <- "uk, uk  money too too")
DT[, output := paste(strsplit(DT[,col1], "(\\s+)|(?!')(?=[[:punct:]])", perl = TRUE)[[1]][!(strsplit(DT[,col1],"(\\s+)|(?!')(?=[[:punct:]])", perl = TRUE)[[1]] %in%  strsplit(DT[,col2], "(\\s+)|(?!')(?=[[:punct:]])", perl = TRUE)[[1]])], collapse = " ")]
```

No comma though

Comment: [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235288/strsplit-on-all-spaces-and-punctuation-except-apostrophes)